MudBlazor - Multiline MudTextField not submitting form
In MudBlazor I have a MudTextField with AutoGrow and MaxLines enabled.

The default behaviour of the multiline MudTextField is to add a new line when pressing "Enter"...
My goal is to get a new line when pressing Shift + Enter and to submit when pressing Enter only.
I already tried using KeyDownPreventDefault according to this post (Prevent new line on hit Enter Key on MudField (MudBlazor) in blazor application) but without much success
My code in TryMudBlazor here

<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
    <MudCard Style="width: 100%" Class="mb-3">
        <MudCardContent>
            <MudTextField
                T="string"
                Immediate="true"
                OnKeyDown="HandleKeyDown"
                KeyDownPreventDefault="_preventDefault"
                @bind-Value="model.Prompt"
                Placeholder="Type a message..."
                Variant="Variant.Filled"
                For="@(() => model.Prompt)"
                AutoGrow
                MaxLines="14"/>
        </MudCardContent>
        <MudCardActions Class="pt-0">
            <MudSpacer/>
            <MudTooltip Text="Submit">
                <MudIconButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Send" Size="Size.Small" Color="Color.Primary"></MudIconButton>
            </MudTooltip>
        </MudCardActions>
    </MudCard>
    @foreach (var message in messages) {
        <div>@message</div>
    }
</EditForm>

@code {
    public string Prompt { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    bool _preventDefault;
    List<string> messages = new();
    PromptForm model = new PromptForm();

    public class PromptForm
    {
        [Required]
        public string Prompt { get; set; }
    }

    protected void HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        _preventDefault = e.Key == "Enter" && !e.ShiftKey;
    }

    public void OnValidSubmit(EditContext context) {
        model.Prompt = string.Empty;
        messages.Add("Submit Successful");
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

Problem
When clicking the "Send" button manually OnValidSubmit is getting called and the success message Submit Successful is getting printed.
Pressing Shift + Enter adds a new line as desired
BUT
When pressing Enter only nothing happens althogh the same success message should appear
